# Angular Reactive form: Unable to bind checkbox checked property on page load

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In Angular Reactive forms i want Two-way data binding of Checkbox, after checking it i am dispatching check variable it to the store and after page load i am getting the new updated value also. But that checkbox `isdateChkd` variable even though its coming **TRUE** checkbox is not getting auto checked on page load.

Below are both HTML and ts files..

**HTML File**

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
   <div class="abc" formControlName="inputDate">
     <div class="xyz">
       <p-calendar formControlName="inputDate" 
       [(ngModel)]="inputDateValue"
       class="abc"/>

       <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1" class="abc" name="dateChk"
       name="dateIsChecked" [(ngModel)]="isdateChkd" (change)="chkFunction($event.target.value)" />
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

**Component.ts file**

```
public isdateChkd: boolean = false;

 ngOnInit() {

....Other service calls

// Call to get isdateChkd value

this.store.select(getValues).takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe).subscribe((data) => {

this.isdateChkd = data.defaultUpdate // this value holds boolean to be used


});

}

chkFunction(valule) {
 this.isdateChkd = value; // i get update when checkbox is checked

this.store.dispatch(new updateCheckboxCheckedService(value)); // after its checked dispatching it to the store
}
```

Thanks in advance for help...

Comment: Did you tried `[checked]` in place of `ngModel`

Comment: I'm not sure why you are using both reactive forms as well as template driven forms together. Angular must be giving you an error in the console. Use either one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`checked`** attribute along with `NgModel`.

It's working here with checked along with the value *`isdateChkd`*. You can also  check here in this [stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ldtvkj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Please try to make changes like below code

```
    ...
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1" class="abc" name="dateIsChecked" 
         [(ngModel)]="isdateChkd" (change)="chkFunction($event)" checked="isdateChkd" />
    ...
```

Happy Coding.. :)

Comment: after saving and dispatching to ngrx store, after opening the page again, even though i saved after unchecking it, it is always coming as checked. Even when the boolean returned from server is FALSE. What to do now ?

Comment: Have you set the value for `this.isdateChkd` in `ngOnInit()`..?

Comment: Yes as you can see in TS file that i mentioned in the question, after every save page gets reloaded and 2 tabs are opened, when i switch to the required tab i can see it as checked even though under `ngOnInit` i am getting `this.isdateChkd = false`

Comment: But as you can see it's working in the stackBlitz when you set it to false on Update click. Thinking there might another event that setting value to True, If possible try to create a stackBlitz with the error that can help us to resolve this.. :)